# Write a docx file using Apache POI Word JAVA

Tags: java, apache-poi, file-writing

I am using Apache POI Word to create a docx file in java.

Right now I am using the following code

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
  XWPFParagraph tmpParagraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun tmpRun = tmpParagraph.createRun();
  tmpRun.setText(newDocxData);

  try {
     document.write(new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\test.docx")));
  } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(PersonnelFileHandlingStreamAttributesHandlerImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  } catch (IOException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(PersonnelFileHandlingStreamAttributesHandlerImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
```

But this puts the whole text under one paragraph.

But I want to put the given sttring into the document as it is.

I tried converting the string to a input stream and passing it when creating the document

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(inputstream);
```

But it also gives an error. Any solution for this?

This is a sample of the string I want to write.

> 10 - SchaumburgIllinois - US       xxx                                                                                                    2018-06-28
>
> Certificate of employment
>
> This is to certify that John is currently employed at xxx as Manager.
>
> John has worked at xxx since 07-DEC-00.
>
> Current salary is SalaryPerMonth SalaryCurrencyCode per month, working
>   100 % of a 40-hour week.

Comment: What exactly contains the `String` `newDocxData`? Where does it come from? You need parsing that string to separate it into different paragraphs and text runs.

Comment: that string contains some text extracted from a word document. when I print it in the console, it prints with the formatting. So I just want to create another document without adding new paragraphs and all that.

Comment: Can you add the contents of the string, in a simple short manner, so it is clear what you want, and what is happening right now

Comment: Actually I am reading a template document and replacing some strings and creating a new file. I think this would simplify my requirement

Comment: @AxelRichter any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Forget it. Since you talked about "formatting", I thought about more complex paragraph contents. With your example string: Split it on "\n" or on "\r\n" and then do creating a paragraph and a text run for each part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem here is that you are retrieving all the text in one String. you should parse all the body element from your document by using "getBodyElements" and then loop through all of them and initiate a paragraph for each element. here is an example of how to do that:

```
 public static XWPFDocument MergeDocument(XWPFDocument source, XWPFDocument output){

        for(IBodyElement element : source.getBodyElements()) {
           if(element instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
                XWPFParagraph paragraph = (XWPFParagraph)element;
                if(paragraph.getStyleID()!=null){
                    XWPFStyles styles= output.createStyles();
                    XWPFStyles stylesdoc2= source.getStyles();
                    styles.addStyle(stylesdoc2.getStyle(paragraph.getStyleID()));
                }    
                XWPFParagraph x= output.createParagraph();
                x.setStyle(((XWPFParagraph) element).getStyle());
                XWPFRun runx=x.createRun();
                runx.setText(((XWPFParagraph) element).getText());
            }
        }
return output;
    }
```